# Conversion from ANSI to Oracle Join Syntax

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I would like to convert the following query:

```
SELECT
    request.requestId
FROM
    request
    LEFT OUTER JOIN incident ON incident.requestId = request.requestId
    LEFT OUTER JOIN changeRequest ON changeRequest.requestId = request.requestId
```

into it's Oracle join syntax equivalent. My first attempt:

```
SELECT
    request.requestId
FROM
    request,
    incident,
    changeRequest
WHERE
    incident.requestId = request.requestId(+)
    AND changeRequest.requestId = request.requestId(+)
```

does not work because of the "ORA-01417: a table may be outer joined to at most one other table" error.

I realise that Oracle recommend using the ANSI approach, however I am "suffering" from the following Oracle bug:

http://awads.net/wp/2007/06/14/when-ansi-sql-join-syntax-does-not-work-in-oracle/

Thanks in advance,
Ben

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have the (+) on the wrong side, it should be:

```
SELECT
    request.requestId
FROM
    request,
    incident,
    changeRequest
WHERE
    incident.requestId (+)= request.requestId
    AND changeRequest.requestId (+)= request.requestId
```

BTW I assume you realse this is the **old** Oracle syntax?  Oracle has supported ANSI joins for a long time now.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Please see http://awads.net/wp/2007/06/14/when-ansi-sql-join-syntax-does-not-work-in-oracle/ for the answer to your question. I would use the ANSI syntax if I could, trust me!

Answer (score 0):

FYI, in our painful experience, complex ANSI inner joins in Oracle (versions 10,11, and 12) occasionally cause ORA-00600 errors (core dumps).  We have been forced to backtrack many of our ANSI joins back to Oracle joins to avoid this.

Comment: This should be posted as a comment rather than an answer.